# Do not feature questions from other communities in side bar if "Hide Hot Network Questions" is selected

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, sidebar, featured-site

I regularly reference StackOverflow at work. I stay logged in to StackExchange so that I can hide Hot Network Questions using the "Hide Hot Network Questions" profile option, which is a feature I value.

Today I noticed a side bar item that I have not seen in a long time: an individual question highlighted from a different community.

[image: Featured question from a community other than StackOverflow in the sidebar]

I think all the reasons why someone would want to avoid seeing the Hot Network Question sidebar apply to these featured questions. Please do not show these featured questions if a user has selected the "Hide Hot Network Questions" profile option.

Comment: @Adam just curious, does the algorithm showing those questions on side bar taking them from the pool of Hot Network Questions, or does it have its own calculation? Thanks. :)

Comment: This is a legitimate request that makes a lot of sense. Still, I can't help, but wonder: why don't you use AdBlock? Proper ad-blocking software will solve your problem and you won't even have to stay logged in.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou It's similar but slightly different. Same selection criteria as the regular HNQ list, but only pulling from the list of public betas and cached separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this by using an ad-blocker. I personally use [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm), but there are others that you can use.

Additionally, if you earn the ["Reduced Ads"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) privilege, you can disable these in your Preferences page. The option is right under the "Hide Hot Network Questions" option.

Comment: Coincidentally I just now got the Reduced Ads privilege, so that works for me, but I would still like to see an official solution that does not require 200 rep or an ad-blocker.

Comment: @DanielO You should always use an ad-blocker for stackoverflow, see I meta.stackexchange.com/a/331963/237989